# Searching in multiple columns using Full Text Search(FTS) with multiple tokens using OR operator

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I am using FTS for querying my database for increasing the search speed as I need to search in text description also,

When I am trying to query using single column its working fine like below

```
select * from productsearch where productsearch match ('prod_name:panasonic*tw*')
```

And also,

```
select * from productsearch where productsearch match ('prod_short_desc:samsung*s5*')
```

So, above both queries give me expected result but when I try to combine both queries using `OR` operator its not giving me any result

```
select * from productsearch where productsearch match ('prod_name:panasonic*tw* OR
                                                         prod_short_desc:samsung*s5*')
```

So, I want to know if I am doing anything wrong in here while using `OR` operator for searching multiple columns

**UPDATE**

Below query is working fine but that doesn't fulfill my requirement,

```
select * from productsearch where productsearch match ('prod_name:panasonic* OR 
                                                            prod_short_desc:samsung*')
```

You can see that if I remove the multiple tokens then its working fine with `OR` operator too.

Comment: I know nothing about FTS, but... could you try: `match ('prod_name:panasonic*tw*' OR 'prod_short_desc:samsung*s5*')`  (separated strings in the same match clause) **or** `match ('prod_name:panasonic*tw*') OR match('prod_short_desc:samsung*s5*')` (separated match clauses)?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein tried both, doesn't work 1st one give all result it means it completed skips the conditions & 2nd one gives wrong paramters to function match()

Comment: Well, just a trial... I thougth it would work like a normal clause (say like when you want to check if a month is even and a day is odd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I found the solution finally,

instead of searching from all the columns individually, I created a single column in the database which contains data for required columns to be searched into,

Example

I need to search in `prod_name` & `prod_short_desc` columns, so I created a column named `data` in database and appended the values of `prod_name` & `prod_short_desc` then looking up into only `data` field worked like a charm

**prod_name** | **prod_short_desc**

```
samsung  | samsung s5
```

So, now I merged the data of both the columns into one with space as a seperator

**data**

*samsung samsung s5*

And then search was very fast indeed with below query,

```
select * from productsearch where productsearch match ('samsung*s5*')
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLite's FTS supports only simple prefix searches.

A query like `prod_short_desc:samsung*s5*` consists of two expressions, `prod_short_desc:samsung*` and `s5*`, which behave exactly the same as if you had written `prod_short_desc:samsung* s5*`.

If you have compiled SQLite for the enhanced query syntax, you could use a query like:

```
prod_short_desc:samsung* prod_short_desc:s5* OR prod_name:panasonic* prod_name:tw*
```

If you have compiled SQLite for the standard query syntax, you cannot use a single query for this because the OR operator's precedence is too high and cannot be modified with parentheses.

Comment: same problem, no results!