# SQlite full-text search MATCH miltiple columns with OR and AND

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, fts4

I am learning how to use [FTS4](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) in SQlite and trying to translate something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE (postal_code LIKE q1 OR place_name LIKE q1) AND (address LIKE q2)
```

which works perfectly with the normal table, to something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE table MATCH '(postal_code: q1 OR place_name: q1) AND (address: q2)'
```

which is not working with the same table converted to VIRTUAL .. USING fts4...

Searching for match in specific column with "**:**" [is working](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#termprefix), but how can I combine this with OR and AND?

Background - I try to work with a flexible query, where q1 can be one of the both: postal-code or place name and q2 has to be address.

**EDIT:**

This is what I got so far (partially) working

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH ('postal_code:q1 OR place_name:q1')
INTERSECT
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table MATCH ('address:q2');
```

(building on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26021690/6049386) post from @CL)

The first problem here are words with space - if I search for something like

```
...MATCH ('postal_code:"new haven*" OR place_name:"new_haven*"')
```

then I have "malformed MATCH expression"
The second problem is when I have empty query, like

```
...MATCH ('*')
```

then I get nothing

Comment: Is your FTS [compiled with the enhanced query syntax](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#compiling_and_enabling_fts3_and_fts4)?

Comment: I suppose yes, because [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26021690/6049386) is working, anyway only with a single OR.